# Mailgun console.log(body) returning undefined

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, mailgun

I am using Mailgun to send email when user click on button to book.

The following is my code:

```
import mailgun from 'mailgun-js';

const book = () => {
    
   const DOMAIN = 'azaleflowerbar.com';
   const api_key = '**********5d721598c7d08095-07bc7b05-******'; //hidden for privacy
  const mg = mailgun({apiKey: api_key, domain: DOMAIN, host: "api.eu.mailgun.net"});
  const data = {
    from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
    to: 'myemail@gmail.com, ',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
  };

  mg.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    console.log(body);
  });
  }
```

What i get though from console.log(body) is "undefined".

I have tried this same code with the sandbox and it works fine (the message is queued).

Also, mailgun DNS for my domain are verified.
I am in touch with mailgun support but they cannot be of any help.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Just a guess based on the limited information provided, but my instinct tells me that the server you're working on is blocking outbound connections.  Test if you can make outbound connections to any outside service.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Brian. But could you please direct me on how to check for outbound connections from the server? I am not really sure what you mean. Thanks

Comment: This is what i have on my AWS EC2 instance: Port range - All   /   
Protocol - All   /   
Destination - 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem - did you find a solution?

Comment: For some reason I had to write apiKey directly in mg instead of recalling it through the constant. Hoptlw this works for you too